# Laravel how to achieve after the session timeout lock screen

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I tried a number of ways from the Internet, but they are not able to achieve, I hope someone can give me a way of achieving ideas or methods, thank you for your help.

Comment: what do you mean by "after the session timeout lock screen"?

Comment: User login timeout, only enter the password, rather than the second login,thank you for your reply:)

Comment: Do you mean automatic logout after some time?

Comment: That's it!Soft log off

Comment: !['imge'](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2016/12/07/5847b6a988c5e.png)

Comment: You can achieve this by defining a custom session timeout middleware which would redirect to the login page with the timedout user's id and cookie. Then in the login page view you could set up the view such that if the request contains user id and cookie display lock page partial or else display the login form partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me provide an example. Define a `SessionTimeout` middleware in the `app\Http\Middleware` folder.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Session;

class SessionTimeout
{


     /**
     * Check the incoming request for session data, log out if session lifetime is exceeded.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {

        //$isLoggedIn = $request->path() != '/logout';

        $bag = Session::getMetadataBag();

        $max = $this->getTimeOut();

        if (($bag && $max < (time() - $bag->getLastUsed()))) {

            //$cookie = cookie('intend', $isLoggedIn ? url()->current() : 'auth/login');

            $email = Auth::user()->email;

            $returnPath = url()->current();

            $request->session()->flush(); // remove all the session data

            Auth::logout(); // logout user

            return redirect('auth/login')
                    ->withInput(compact('email', 'returnPath'))
                    //->withCookie($cookie)
                    ->withErrors(['Please login']);
            //you could also redirect to lock-screen, a completely different view 
            //and then pass the returnPath to controller method maybe via hidden filed
            //to redirect to the last page/path the user was on 
            //after successful re-login from the lock-screen.
        }

        return $next($request);


     }

     /**
     * Set a variable in .env file TIMEOUT (in seconds) to play around in the development machine.
     */
     protected function getTimeOut()
     {
        return (env('TIMEOUT')) ?: (config('session.lifetime') * 60);
     }
}
```

The add `SessionTimeout` to the `app\Http\Kernel.php`

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel {
 /**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $middleware = [
      'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
      'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
      'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
      'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
      'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
      'App\Http\Middleware\SessionTimeout'
 ];
 /**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
      'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
      'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
      'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated'
 ];
```

}

Then in the view for login form generally in `resources\views\auth\login.blade.php`

```
@extend('app-layout')
@section('content')
    //code to display errors here

    @if($email) //check if the request has $email returned by SessionTimeout middleware
        //if so display lock screen like
        //code to display the profile image
        //code to display the user email (or whatever id is used)
    @else
        //display email input field for a new login
        //code to input the email (whatever id is used) for a new login
    @endif
    //here the code common for lock screen as well as new login.
    //code to display input password 
    //code for submit button and rest of the things like remember me field
@stop
```

You can also use partials for lock screen and new login form and display based on `@if($email)`.

Hope this would get you started.

Comment: @KylinSky Please Share the solution you found

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the session driver to handle your authentication, you can change the time period for an idle session to expire in the

**/app/config/session.php file.**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,    // minutes

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Comment: Sorry, my scene is a login page and a lock screen page, I would like to jump to the lock screen after the session expired pages, but I can not start.